# Licensing your work

Tags: security, digital-signature, signing

Let's say I am selling some PHP scripts, developed from scratch by me, and also some Flash games, also developed from scratch by me.

I sold the flash games and PHP scripts to some clients, and to some of them I even sold them with source codes.

Now if one customer will sell the code to someone else without my approval, and that someone else, the 3rd person would claim that the code belongs to him, what can be done?

Can PHP scripts or codes be signed online or something like that?

Comment: Nothing can be  done to prevent this from a technological standpoint.  If they have the source code, they have the source code.  "What can be done" is more of a legal/copyright issue,and as such is off-topic.

Comment: So a solution would be to copyright my code ?

Comment: I'd answer that but it's off-topic for the site.  I'm sorry, but I'm not a lawyer, and it's not my place to be giving out legal advice.  However, in the spiriti of being helpful, I'd recommnd you start here: http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/

Comment: I'll add this:  The idea of protecting code has come up on this site in various guises. (How to prevent decompiling my .NET code, for example).  The general answer is "You can't prevent it.  You have to accept that your code can be stolen."  Same deal the music industry execs have to accept and have been fighting with since Cassette Tapes allowed us to record songs off the Radio.  All you can do is make your product so good people are willing to pay for it.

Comment: Yes, you are right . Piracy can be slowed , but it cannot be stopped. I guess that what I have to do is to learn to compete against my own product with updates and features and better support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sold to clients, does the contract stipulate that they are forbidden to sell it ? Also more importantly does the contract also specify that the client must not modify in anyway the source code and then sell it ?

Today, the best way to protect your I.P. is to use a lawyer and yes, this is a sad thing.

Comment: Yes, it stipulates that the client is forbidden to sell it. And if he makes changes to the code , then if any problems appear after changing the code , I do not cover them, but I offer support for the original code.  I have all the source codes, history and other data on my PC. If someone with knowledge would look into my PC , he will see that it is my code. And I am selling the code for about 2 years. I have older clients that can demonstrate this.

Comment: Yes, it should count. But your best bet is to talk to a lawyer in this field and also to find out if there are people selling you code/script.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve a social problem by technological means. This won't work.

If someone does that to you, you should get a lawyer and sue him.